# Import a function in a .mjs script

Tags: javascript, ecma, mjs

Need some help with using a .mjs script and .js as well.

I have one script.mjs file that looks like this. Simplifying here (the script needs to be .mjs file)

```
import test from './test.js';

 test();
```

and test.js looks like this. Again simplifying here but it needs to be .js file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const root = path.join(__dirname, '../../');
const statsPath = path.join(
    root,
    'somepath',
);

export function test() {
    const localBuildStat = JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(statsPath, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
    );

    
    let assetSizes = {};
    
    const assets = localBuildStat.assets;
    assets.forEach((s) => {
       // do something here       
       }
    });
}
```

when I try to run the script.mjs file, I get this error:

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVdSz.png]

How do you suggest I fix this to work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would just rip the bandage off and use ESM in the entire project. and skip all the dual hazzard problems. and also add type=module in package.json and only use .js

Answer (score 2):

use `module.exports` in commonjs

```
module.exports = function test() {
  // ...
}
```